# java loop memory and disposal of outstanding tasks

Tags: java, loops, memory

Suppose I had a method that went something like this:

```
public void doSomething() {
    doThingA();
    doThingB();
    doThingC();
    doSomething();
}
```

And then let's define one of these methods actions as something like this:

```
public void doThingB() {
    if (x == 1) {
        startDifferentMethodLoop()
    }
}
```

And let's say the `startDiffernetMethodLoop()` has separate methods like `doThingE()` and of course ends by calling iteself  again.

The question: if `doThingB()` becomes active when x is equal to 1, will java queue the oustanding methods in the first loop (specifically `doThingC` and `doSomething` and try to accomplish them once everything is resolved? If so, what would be the preferred way of telling Java that once X is true, and the new loop is called, the outstanding methods do not need to be queued?

Or does Java forget about the original methods because they were never called?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "... once everything is resolved". `doThingC` will be called when `doThingB` returns. If `doThingB` never returns ... that sounds like another issue. And unless there's a `System.exit` lurking somewhere, looking at `doSomething` I don't see how this program ever ends.

Comment: Let's assume both loops have at least one method with a possible System.exit. So the program definitely can end. The question is what happens to the outstanding methods in the first loop once the second loop is called.

Comment: If I'm understanding your confusion correctly, this is called recursion, and previous method calls will *not* be forgotten. Enough recursion calls (or a never ending recursion call) could lead to a `StackOverflowException`

Comment: As @VinceEmigh says, nothing is forgotten. You can think of any given method call as a black box. Whatever craziness that goes on in there, including methods calling themselves, recursively calling each other, whatever, when all that finally "resolves", the next line after the original call will be executed. Play around with `System.out.println(...)` calls at the beginnings and ends of each method and watch what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your methods return a boolean value meaning "resolved", like this:

```
// and similar for other methods
public boolean doThingB() {
    if (x == 1) {
        startDifferentMethodLoop();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void doSomething() {
    if (doThingA()) return;
    if (doThingB()) return;
    if (doThingC()) return;
    doSomething();
}
```